# ImportError cannot import name 'MSO_AUTO' from 'pptx.enum.shapes'

Tags: python, python-pptx

Wy I get an error here:

ImportError: `cannot import name 'MSO_AUTO' from 'pptx.enum.shapes'`

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_AUTO
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation()
title_only_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[5]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_only_slide_layout)

shapes = slide.shapes
left = top = width = height = Inches(1.0)
shape = shapes.add_shape(
    MSO_AUTO.CLOUD, left, top, width, height
)
shape.text = 'something'
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `MSO_AUTO_SHAPE_TYPE` or its shorter alias `MSO_SHAPE`. There is no `pptx.enum.shapes.MSO_AUTO` enumeration in `python-pptx`.